# is it possible to fork a mysqldump of data?

Tags: perl, mysql

I am restoring a mysql database with perl on a remote server with about 30 million records. It's taking > 2 days & looking at my network connections I am not fully utilizing my uplink bandwidth. I will need to do this at least 1x per week. Is there a way to fork a mysqldump (I'm using perl) so that I can take full advantage of my bandwidth (I don't mind if I'm choked off for a bit...I just need to get this done faster).

Comment: The bottleneck is almost certainly your database, not network transfer, so doing two simultaneous transfers is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you upload the whole dump to the remote server and start the restore there?

Comment: Well, if I did it that way I'd run into the same problem where I'm not taking full advantage of my upload bandwidth.

Comment: @user522962: Please clarify: how would the upload bandwidth not be used if you transferred the file?

Comment: not to mention if you do it this way youre going to be using a much smaller filesize if you gzip the dump file. then assuming the mysql server is local to the host you uploaded the file to, it should go much faster... Also if you have a dumpfile.. whay even bother with using perl just load the dump.

Comment: I mean not fully utilized. Forking the process will create multiple, simultaneous uploads, which will be quicker

Comment: @prodigital...true, but the file is still quite large if I gzip it.

Comment: @user522962 If multiple, simultaneous uploads over the same link are quicker, there might be a misconfiguration in your FTP/SSH server.

Answer (score 1):

A restore of a mysqldump is just the execution of a long series of commands that would restore your database from scratch.  If the execution path for that is; 1) send command 2) remote system executes command 3) remote system replies that the command is complete 4) send next command, then you are spending most of your time waiting on network latency.

I do know that most SQL hosts will allow you to upload a dump file specifically to avoid the kinds of restore time that you're talking about.  The company that takes my money each month even has a web-based form that you can use to restore a database from a file that has been uploaded via sftp.  Poke around your hosting service's documentation.  They should have something similar.  If nothing else (and you're comfortable on the command line) you can upload it directly to your account and do it from a shell there.

Answer (score 1):

[mk-parallel-dump](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-dump.html) and [mk-parallel-restore](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-restore.html) are designed to do what you want, but in my testing mk-parallel-dump was actually slower than plain old mysqldump. Your mileage may vary.

(I would guess the biggest factor would be the number of spindles your data files reside on, which in my case, 1, was not especially conducive to parallelization.)

First caveat: mk-parallel-* writes a bunch of files, and figuring out when it's safe to start sending them (and when you're done receiving them) may be a little tricky. I believe that's left as an exercise for the reader, sorry.

Second caveat: mk-parallel-dump is specifically advertised as not being for backups. Because "At the time of this release there is a bug that prevents --lock-tables from working correctly," it's really only useful for databases that you know will not change, e.g., a slave that you can STOP SLAVE on with no repercussions, and then START SLAVE once mk-parallel-dump is done.

I think a better solution than parallelizing a dump may be this:

If you're doing your mysqldump on a weekly basis, you can just do it once (dumping with --single-transaction (which you should be doing anyway) and --master-data=n) and then start a slave that connects over an ssh tunnel to the remote master, so the slave is continually updated. The disadvantage is that if you want to clone a local copy (perhaps to make a backup) you will need enough disk to keep an extra copy around. The advantage is that a week's worth of (query-based) replication log is probably quite a bit smaller than resending the data, and also it arrives gradually so you don't clog your pipe.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't set up a slave as we don't have permissions from the remotehost (shared hosting)

Answer (score 1):

How big is your database in total?  What kind of tables are you using?

A big risk with backups using mysqldump has to do with table locking, and updates to tables during the backup process.

The mysqldump backup process basically works as follows:

```
For each table {
   Lock table as Read-Only
   Dump table to disk
   Unlock table
}
```

The danger is that if you run an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query that affects multiple tables while your backup is running, your backup may not capture the results of your query properly.  This is a very real risk when your backup takes hours to complete and you're dealing with an active database.  Imagine - your code runs a series of queries that update tables A,B, and C.  The backup process currently has table B locked.

- The update to A will not be captured, as this table was already backed up.
- The update to B will not be captured, as the table is currently locked for writing.
- The update to C will be captured, because the backup has not reached C yet.

This is an easy way to **destroy** referential integrity in your database.

Your backup process needs to be atomic, and transactional.  If you can't shut down the entire database to writes during the backup process, you're risking disaster.

Also - there must be something wrong here.  At a previous company, we were running nightly backups of a 450G Mysql DB (largest table had 150M rows), and it took less than 6 hours for the backup to complete.

Two thoughts:

1. Do you have a slave database?  Run the backup from there - Stop replication (preventing RW risk), run the backup, restart replication.
2. Are your tables using InnoDB?  Consider investing in [InnoDBhotbackup](http://www.innodb.com/wp/products/hot-backup/), which solves this problem, as the backup process leverages the journaling that is part of the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: I don't have a slave or InnoDB...mine takes longer because our replicated DB is on a remote server & our upload bandwidth isn't very high